Using C# - Import Azure DevOps Repo
I am trying to import a azure devops repo to a new repo within the same project. The following code just returns "Bad Request" and no other information.
public async Task ImportGenericRepository(GitRepository destinationRepository, GitRepository genericRepository, Guid serviceEndpointId)
{
    var importRequest = new GitImportRequest
    {
        Repository = destinationRepository,
        Parameters = new GitImportRequestParameters
        {
            GitSource = new GitImportGitSource
            {
                Url = genericRepository.RemoteUrl,
                Overwrite = false
            },
            DeleteServiceEndpointAfterImportIsDone = true,
            TfvcSource = null,
            ServiceEndpointId = serviceEndpointId
        },
    };
           
    try
    {
        await _connection.GitHttpClient.CreateImportRequestAsync(importRequest, _projectId, destinationRepository.Id);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

}

I tried doing this directly with the HttpClient, I got the same error.

Do you really need to use C# for this operation? See Import a Git repo for other options.

@RuiJarimba We are automating certain tasks. so I do need to use c#

Got it. Anyway, I'd suggest taking a look into the article I posted above because it mentions the required permissions and other details (e.g. use empty repository) that might help you solve your problem.

I would recommend writing domek sort of Shell script to automatem that

Just a quick C# note: That try/catch block is useless and should be removed. The behavior of your application will be exactly the same without it.

@KevinLu-MSFT I've marked the correct answer. My issue was, I was incorrectly creating the service connection.

Based on your current c# sample, I can reproduce the same issue. It will show the Bad Request error.

The cause of the issue can be that you need to use Other Git type Service Connection.
Here are the steps:
Step1: Create Other Git Service Connection in Project Settings -> Service Connections.

Step2: You can set the source repo Url and Personal Acccess Token(PAT) in the Service Connection.
For example:

Step3: Use the Other Git Service Connection in the C# Code.
Here is my example:
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
 
            var _connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/OrgUrl"), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "PAT"));

            string serviceEndpointstring = "6543a4ca-a195-476f-b9f4-7ce6a913773a";
            Guid serviceEndpointId = Guid.Parse(serviceEndpointstring);
            var repoidstring = "21c693ee-c612-4644-9191-d23acee19fab";
            Guid Repoguid = Guid.Parse(repoidstring);
            GitRepository destinationRepository = new GitRepository() { Id= Repoguid, Name ="RepoName" };
            GitRepository genericRepository = new GitRepository() { RemoteUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/org/project/_git/sourcerepo" };
            var importRequest = new GitImportRequest
            {
                Repository = destinationRepository,
                Parameters = new GitImportRequestParameters
                {
                    GitSource = new GitImportGitSource
                    {
                        Url = genericRepository.RemoteUrl,
                        Overwrite = false
                    },
                    DeleteServiceEndpointAfterImportIsDone = true,
                    TfvcSource = null,
                    ServiceEndpointId = serviceEndpointId

                },
            };

            try
            {
                await _connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>().CreateImportRequestAsync(importRequest, "projectid", destinationRepository.Id);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }


        }
    }
}

Note: You need to change this line:
From:
 await _connection.GitHttpClient.CreateImportRequestAsync(importRequest, _projectId, destinationRepository.Id);

To:
 await _connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>().CreateImportRequestAsync(importRequest, "projectid", destinationRepository.Id);

Here is my another answer with the similar issue: Import Repo with Rest API

I tried your code and this is what I observed:
Added below 2 lines for the test code to work(ignore this):
var credentials = new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "test-pat");
VssConnection _connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(@"https://dev.azure.com/my-org"), credentials);

had to update this line:
await _connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>().CreateImportRequestAsync(importRequest, _projectId, destinationRepository.Id);

When I provide ServiceEndpointId under GitImportRequest, it shows below error in Azure Devops portal:

And It works fine when I remove the usage of ServiceEndpointId at all:

Perhaps you could try without this line ServiceEndpointId = serviceEndpointId, and even better, you may update the post and share how you are calling this method and the values you are providing ?
